# Flutter, how to change current tabbar screen without using tab library button

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I implemented tab bar in my application

and then I want tabbar screens to be change when the specific moments occur

but buttons should not be used (for instance, bottom navigation bar buttons)

if you have three tab buttons and assume current screen is first(index 0),

how to accomplish to go to page third?(index 2)

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect TabBar change in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485466/how-to-detect-tabbar-change-in-flutter)

Comment: @Mrvd thanks but I do not think so

Answer (score 0):

If you have a TabController even if you don't have a TabBar(but you have a TabBarView with that controller attached) then just use the method animateTo() with the index you want to move and a duration for the animation (if you want a different duration). `tabController.animateTo(2)`