# Flutter - Bottom Navigation Bar changing page, but not icon selected

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Basically, I have a main widget that has a `this._bottomNavigationBar` and when the screen will change, I pass it to the new screen. Then, each screen has its own `Scaffold` and `AppBar`.

Sounds perfectly, but it's not working properly.

When I click to change the selected option, it changes the screen, but the selected icon keeps the same. If I print the `this.currentIndex`, it changes the index normally. Something that I was not expecting to happen, because when I declare the `this._bottomNavigationBar`, the `currentIndex` property is defined like that: `currentIndex: this.currentIndex`, so if the icon isn't changing, then the variable won't either.

So, I realized that I probably forgive to use the `setState()` method on the onTap, but it wasn't the case.

I just don't know why this is happening. I think it's something about the `setState` "scope", maybe? I'll leave my code below to illustrate this better.

#### home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'landing.dart';

const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> homeScreenNavbarItems = [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
    title: Text(''),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
    title: Text(''),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark),
    title: Text(''),
  ),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Icon(Icons.person),
    title: Text(''),
  ),
];

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomeState();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int currentIndex = 1;
  BottomNavigationBar _bottomNavigationBar;
  List homeScreens;

  void onNavbarTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      this.currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    this._bottomNavigationBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF000000),
      unselectedItemColor: Color(0xFFb3b3b3),
      currentIndex: this.currentIndex,
      items: homeScreenNavbarItems,
      onTap: this.onNavbarTapped,
    );

    this.homeScreens = [
      LandingScreen(this._bottomNavigationBar),
      Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: this._bottomNavigationBar,
      )
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(this.currentIndex);
    return this.homeScreens.elementAt(this.currentIndex);
  }
}
```

#### landing.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class LandingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final BottomNavigationBar _bottomNavigationBar;

  LandingScreen(this._bottomNavigationBar);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LandingScreenState();
  }
}

class _LandingScreenState extends State<LandingScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('a'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
            Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: widget._bottomNavigationBar,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `main.dart` file is simply calling the `Home` widget, so I didn't place it here.

#### Edit

I removed all the content of the initState method and placed then into the Widget build method, worked, but I don't know exactly why...

Comment: In my opinion, the problem related to context. You can create a new class and put homeScreenNavbarItems inside it.

Comment: Refer my Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62473536/12037365

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the `BottomNavigationBar` is configured in initState. When **currentIndex** has been updated after calling `setState`, the properties aren't updated because it's inside initState instead of `Widget build`.