# Show a message dialog before navigation to next tab flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a TabBarView(), and i need to show a MessageDialog (showDialog) asking if really want to leave this tab. is there any way to do it?

this is the body of my code

```
child: Scaffold(
        drawer: SideMenu(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Antecedentes"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            controller: _controller,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Tab # 1'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab # 2'),
              Tab(text: 'Tab # 3'),

          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          controller: _controller,
          children: [
            TabOnePage(),
            TabTwoPage(),
            TabThreePage(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Im using version 2.2.3 of Flutter.
I appreciate help on this .

Comment: check this out and let me know if it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485466/how-to-detect-tabbar-change-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show `AlertDialog` on `Tabbar` onTap action, and set TabBar index to previous one(this will allow TabBar to stay on the same tab):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Tabbar Demo"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            onTap: (index) {
              print(index);
              showAlert(tabController.index);
              tabController.index = tabController.previousIndex;
            },
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.chat)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.drafts)),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit))
            ],
            controller: tabController,
            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomView("First"),
            CustomView("Second"),
            CustomView("Third"),
          ],
          controller: tabController,
        ));
  }
```

And upon selection of the "OK" button in the AlertDialog, set `Tabbar` index to the new one.

```
  void showAlert(int newIndex) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog(
      content: new Container(
        height: 80.0,
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text("Want to leave this tab?"),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                tabController.index = newIndex;
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    showDialog(context: context, child: alertDialog);
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what i needed, although i had to make some changes due version of flutter, it worked . :)

Comment: this works great however it doesn't detect the case of tab that was changed by swipe, any idea how to enhance it to support also this case ?